# Structural Dynamics Numerical Method Question: Does it Belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just wonder whether numerical solution to structural dynamic question belongs here, or belongs to Math SE?

An example of such a question would be: What is [the stability of Newmark numerical method when applied to transient problems](http://www.fs.cvut.cz/en/u2052/node113.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Try it; since all numerics proposals are stuck in Area51, we could host some questions like this here.